# MKMapView won't respond to touching or pinching

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

So I have a MKMapVie object and it is set up as follows:

```
    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                               [Screen width],
                                                               [Screen height])];
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self addSubview:mapView];
```

And I set its location to be the current user location with the following method.

```
- (void) locateUser {

    float z2 = 0.003 * 4.0;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(z2, z2);
    [self.mapView setRegion: MKCoordinateRegionMake(currentLocation, span) animated:YES];
}
```

However once the map zooms to the users location it will not allow me to move the map around or pinch or zoom. Is there something i'm missing?
Thanks.

Comment: try to add the following: self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  Probably the view which contains the map does not allow user interactions.

Comment: [mapView setZoomEnabled:TRUE];

Comment: Nope, neither of these seem to work. Should zooming and panning work by default?

Comment: if the above two don't work, you will need to show more code because the issues lies elsewhere.  How/when are you calling locateUser?

Comment: When locationDidUpdate from CLLocationManagerDelegate is called thats when I update the currentLocation and call loateUser after that.